# Mongoose returns undefined when I try to access an element of a doc that I queried for

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

Context: I am trying to simply console log a value from a document that I queried for. I am successfully finding the document. I know because I print out the doc before I print out the value of the doc I am looking for. The doc prints find, the field on the other hand comes out as undefined.

Here is the code:

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let TextSchema = new Schema({
    text_ID: {type: Number, required: true},
    title: {type: String, required: true, max: 100},
    body: {type: String, required: true},
});


// Export the model
module.exports = mongoose.model('texts', TextSchema);
```

I know that Mongo creates its own IDs for everything but bear with me on my own ID's for now.
Here is the problematic code:

```
textModel.find({text_ID: currentTextLocation}, function(err, doc){
        if(err){
          console.log('error: ' + err);
        }
        console.log(doc);
        console.log(doc.body);
        currentTextBody = doc.body;
      });
```

Here is the output it gives me:

```
Database connection established!
[
  {
    _id: 5dc2915f1c9d440000ed7077,
    text_ID: 1,
    title: 'Kevin Abstract',
    body: 'Kevin Abstract was a famous american rap artist.'
  }
]
undefined
```

Finally here is what it should look like:

```
Database connection established!
[
  {
    _id: 5dc2915f1c9d440000ed7077,
    text_ID: 1,
    title: 'Kevin Abstract',
    body: 'Kevin Abstract was a famous american rap artist.'
  }
]
Kevin Abstract was a famous american rap artist.
```

I have made sure that the schema relates to the correct collection. I tried printing the type of doc, that returned an object.

Comment: From the o/p of doc which looks to be an array (*array of documents if more than 1*). try accessing the body as `doc[0]["body"]`

Comment: Wish I could give you the little green flag because that worked. I do not really get why it worked but I am happy that it did.